# Issue searching List of Objects (javascript) in Lightning Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript

Essentially what I want to do is search my list of objects which are pushed using my handle products function. Once the list has been populated I need to search if the list.CardType contains "Card Present" then set a variable in my component to True.
I am being shown this error, but I have done some checks and its lead me to believe my handleNext function is the problem.

Any Ideas?

ERROR :

> Uncaught Action failed: c:AddProductsComponent$controller$handleNext
>   [Cannot read property '0' of undefined]

```
<aura:attribute name="productList"  type="List"/>
```

**Controller**

```
handleProduct: function(cmp, evt, helper){
var ProductId = cmp.find("productType").get("v.value"); 
var ProductName = cmp.find("productType").get("v.value");
var MIDname = cmp.get("v.selectedRecord.Name");
var MIDid = cmp.get("v.selectedRecord.Id");
var cardType = cmp.get("v.cardType");
var PL = cmp.get("v.productList");
cmp.set("v.options", ProductName);
/* Creating the new product to add to the list. */
var product = {
    MID: MIDname,
    MIDid: MIDid,
    CardType: cardType,
    ProductId: ProductId,
    Name: ProductName}; 
/* Pushed the new product to the list to update the main list  */
PL.push(product);


/* Updating the product list with new product. */
cmp.set("v.productList", PL); 
},

 handleNext: function(cmp, evt){
     list = cmp.get("v.productList");
     for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].CardType == 'Card Present') {
        console.log("True")
        cmp.set("v.showCP", true);
        }
}

    cmp.set("v.showHome", false);
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list[i].CardType` is causing the problem, when `i = 0`, it's trying to dereference `list[0]`, but list is undefined. Start by logging the value of `v.productList` before that loop, and working backwards from there, to see what's going on.